# docker volume prune: Dont delete named volumes

Tags: docker

I have created a volume

```
docker volume create postgresql_db
```

Now i am using it in my docker-compose.xml

```
services:
  postgresql:
    image: "postgres:11-alpine"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: postgresql_data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
        volume:
          nocopy: true        
    environment:
      PGDATA: '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata'
    networks:  # connect to the bridge
      - postgresql_network
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "log_statement=all","-c", "log_destination=stderr"]

volumes: 
  postgresql_data:
    external: true
```

Sometimes i want to stop and clean the docker system.

So I try to run

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq) # stop all containers 
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) # remove all containers
docker container prune
docker image prune
docker network prune
docker volume prune  #<-- remove all dangling volumes also
```

this also delete `postgresql_data` i.e `named volume`

how to avoid that.

Answer (score 6):

As of Docker 23.0.0, this is the default behavior of `docker volume prune`, it will only clean anonymous volumes. For anyone that needs to go back to the old behavior and prune named volumes too, you need to add a filter to include named volumes:

```bash
docker volume prune --filter all=true
```

It's also useful to use labels to control what is cleaned, e.g. I create volumes in test scenarios with a test label and then explicitly prune only those:

```bash
docker volume create --label=preserve volume-to-keep
docker volume create --label=test volume-to-prune
# ... run tests
docker volume prune -f --filter label=test --filter all=true
```

The above requires that you are explicitly creating every volume and not relying on anonymous volumes. You would then avoid setting that label on volume you want to preserve.

---

**Original answer for docker versions before 23.x.x**

There's no option to the `docker volume prune` command for this. There's also no metadata on the volume that indicates it's an anonymous volume, it's just a named volume with a random hex name. The best I do is list the dangling volumes and delete the ones with a long hex name. As long as your named volumes are not exactly 64 hex characters, they won't be included in this:

```
docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | egrep '^[a-z0-9]{64}$' | \
  xargs --no-run-if-empty docker volume rm
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-volumes), you can simply filter your volumes (by label, for instance):

```sh
docker volume prune --filter label!=postgresql_db
```

then all volumes that are **not** (look at the `!`) named *postgresql_db* and are not attached to 1 or more containers will be removed.

Comment: great! I would appreciate if you accept it :)

Comment: But this will not solve my question. I am looking for excluding all named volumes. Without need to mention their names

Comment: Well, I don't get it. Your question's title is `Dont delete named volumes` and in the end you say that you do want to avoid Docker deleting `postgresql_data`. `docker volume prune` deletes all volumes (even the named ones) that are not in use by 1 or more containers

Comment: Oh, do you mean `excluding all named volumes` **from beind deleted**, right? Now it makes sense. About that, I don't think Docker has a native way for doing that. Actually, there is an interesting discussion about that on [this Moby's issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31757).
As a workaround, you could adopt a pattern in your named volumes (using `_` ou prefixing with `volume` word) and filter by that using `grep` or `awk`

Comment: But this feature is required, else we will loose all data. or have to rely on mounting data outside the git repository, so git checkout will not replace that folder

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried it and it deleted the filtered volume as well

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.
Delete all unnamed volumes:

```
docker volume prune --filter "label!=com.docker.compose.volume"
```

Answer (score 0):

`docker rm` offers the flag `-v` which is deleting all anonymous volumes corresponding to this container.

If you want to prune the dangling ones as well (not associated to any container you're currently running) do the `docker volume prune` before stopping and removing the running ones.

Therefore:

```
docker volume prune  #<-- remove all dangling volumes also
docker stop $(docker ps -aq) # stop all containers 
docker rm -v $(docker ps -a -q) # remove all containers
docker container prune
docker image prune
docker network prune
```